# Determining requirements for a GET request

Tags: javascript, ajax, http-get

Yahoo! Sports offers a new feature to set your fantasy team lineup for a particular day.  It works via a simple URL like so:

```
http://hockey.fantasysports.yahoo.com/hockey/{leagueId}/{teamId}/startactiveplayers?date={yyyy}-{mm}-{dd}&crumb={crumb}
```

If I fill in the parameters and visit the page **in a browser** it works fine.

If I try and and **automate** the process (the idea being I can set my lineup for the rest of the season and only tweak as I need to) it doesn't work.

I tried submitting the request using a an AJAX call which returns a non-descriptive error with no response object, as well as a Phantom JS call which returns a successful response though the lineup change has not actually taken effect.

How can I figure out what is missing?

*Edit*: Here's a look at a sample AJAX request:

```
Request URL:http://hockey.fantasysports.yahoo.com/hockey/56377/3/startactiveplayers?date=2013-1-22&crumb=DmhVvCa0WXX
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Origin:null
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.52 Safari/537.17
Query String Parametersview sourceview URL encoded
date:2013-1-22
crumb:DmhVvCa0WXX
```

And the response:

```
readyState: 0
responseText: ""
status: 0
statusText: "error"
```

Comment: Are you sending the request through your server to avoid cross-domain issues?

Comment: I'm running it on a local server, didn't think GET requests were affected by cross-domain.

Comment: Unfortunately they are. You'll want to build a proxy to communicate with the Yahoo Fantasy API to send and return data. You'll probably need to register your "app" and get OAUTH keys. http://developer.yahoo.com/fantasysports/guide/index.html